# Storyboard / UI Loaded before applicationDidFinishLaunching call is made

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am working on an OS X application which I want to modularise. I currently load the module (bundle) code at application start in the appDelegate's

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification).
```

However, it is a storyboard application and coming from iOS I was surprised to learn that the storyboard, and thus all view controllers contained within it, are loaded before the **applicationDid-** or **willFinishLaunching** calls are made.

The annoying thing is that I need to have the information from the loaded module (bundle) to configure the UI, so before the UI template mehtods are called (view/windowDidLoad).

**I need some place to load the module (bundle) code before the UI/Storyboard is loaded. Any ideas?**

**My Ideas:** I Could retrigger a UI reload manually after the appDelegate calls are made, or use a splash screen window as initial window that does the loading before the main window appears, but I find both of these solutions to be unpleasing.

**Related:** would help me improve my understanding would be an overview of an OS X applications lauch cycle. Similar to the doc of [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW3)

Comment: Use an init method for your delegate...or, possibly, `+initialize`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X storyboard calls viewDidLoad before applicationDidFinishLaunching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681587/os-x-storyboard-calls-viewdidload-before-applicationdidfinishlaunching)