# OS X storyboard calls viewDidLoad before applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsstoryboard

I created a Mac OS X application in Xcode using storyboards. For some reason the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method in the AppDelegate is being called after `viewDidLoad` in the NSViewControllers. As with iOS apps, I thought `viewDidLoad` is supposed to be called before `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? Do storyboards in OS X apps initialize the view controllers before the app has finished launching?

I am using the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method to register default settings into NSUserDefaults. Unfortunately, registering the default values is happening after the views in the storyboard are loaded. Therefore, when I set up the view in each view controller using `viewDidLoad`, the defaults data in NSUserDefaults has not been set. If I can't use `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to register NSUserDefaults in OS X storyboard apps, then how I set the defaults before `viewDidLoad` is called?

To fix this issue, in the `Main.storyboard` in Xcode, I turned off "Is Initial Controller" for the main window. I assigned a storyboard ID to the main window as "MainWindow". Then in the AppDelegate I entered the following code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainWindow = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as! NSWindowController
        mainWindow.showWindow(nil)
        mainWindow.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    }
}
```

The app does not crash but now the window never appears. The following image displays the storyboard I'm working with:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Correct, the lifecycle is a wee bit different in OS X.

Instead of letting the storyboard be your initial interface (this is defined in the General settings of your project), you can instead set up a MainMenu xib file and designate that as your main interface, then in your applicationDidFinishLaunching method in your AppDelegate you can programmatically instantiate your storyboard after you have completed your other initialization code.

I recommend checking out *Cocoa Programming for OS X: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* if you haven't already; one nice thing they do in their book is actually have you get rid of some of the default Xcode template stuff and instead they have you set up your initial view controller the "right" way by doing it explicitly.

You might put something like this in your applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
NSStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyWindowController *initialController = (MyWindowController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"myWindowController"];
[initialController showWindow:self];
[initialController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

This assumes that you've already changed "Main Interface" to something like MainMenu.xib.

Comment: I'm trying your approach (in Swift) but I'm not able to make the window appear. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I assume you did this since you aren't getting a crash but is the storyboard ID set on the NSWindowController for the window?

Comment: Yes, the Storyboard ID is set to MainWindow for the NSUserDefaults Example window that is shown in the screen shot.

Comment: All of the code is in the AppDelegate which I updated to show all the content.

Comment: The life cycle is different, but what is the rational for this difference? Xcode puts a stub for applicationDidFinishLaunching in the template as if it is expected to be used -- what is a use case for this method if not for initializing an app?

Comment: I think you lso need to store the window controller as a strong reference somewhere, or the window will be deallocated and disappear right away (at least it was like that before storyboards)

Comment: @NicolasMiari, I think you are right. One just need to set the WindowController as an attribute of AppDelegate and it works. I put together a snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As the question's author mentioned:

> The app does not crash but now the window never appears.

Despite [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741129/6704959) and [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36682517/6704959) both helpful answers (I already adquire the book you recommended, Aaron, and will start implementing the two-storyboard pattern your way, Nicolas), neither solve the specific problem of the window not showing.

## Solution

You need make your WindowController instance live outside `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`'s scope. To accomplish it, you could declare a `NSWindowController` propriety for your `AppDelegate` class and persist your created WindowController instance there.

### Implementation

*In Swift 4.0*

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var mainWindowController: NSWindowController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: NSNotification) {

        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
        let mainWindow = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "MainWindow")) as! NSWindowController
        mainWindow.showWindow(self)
        mainWindow.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

        // After applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) finished, the WindowController instance will persist.
        self.mainWindowController = mainWindow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36682517/433373), I found out that the separate Interface Builder file containing the menu alone (separate from the window and view controller) **does not need to be a xib;** it too can be a storyboard. This enables us to easily fix as follows:

1. **Duplicate** your original storyboard (Main.storyboard) and **rename** it to "*Menu*.storyboard"
2. **Delete** the window controller and view controller from Menu.storyboard
3. **Delete** the app menu bar from Main.storyboard.
4. Change your app target's "Main Interface" from "Main.storyboard" to "Menu.storyboard".

*(I tried it in my app and it works)*

This avoids having to re-create the app's main menu from scratch, or to figure out how to transplant your existing one from "Main.stroyboard" to "Menu.xib".

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is registering `NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` in your view controllers and move your code from `viewDidLoad` to `applicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification:)
                                             name:NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73659184/6709940)

If you want a piece of code to be run before everything, you can override the `AppDelegate`'s `init()` like this:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    override init() {
        DoSomethingBeforeEverthing()       // You code goes here
        super.init()
    }
...
}
```

Few points to remember:

1. You might want to check, what's allowed/can be done here, i.e. before app delegate is initialized
2. Also cleaner way would be, subclass the `AppDelegate`, and add new delegate method that you call from init, say `applicationWillInitialize` and if needed `applicationDidInitialize`