# Initializing CoreData in macOS

Tags: macos, core-data

In Cocoa, Storyboard's first view controller will call `viewDidLoad` (on the first view controller) before `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called.
Since I am grabbing my `NSManagedObjectContext` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, I need to wait for `applicationDidFinishLaunching` before loading my data.

In other words, in `viewDidLoad`, I don't yet have my `NSManagedObjectContext`.

---

What I'm doing now:

I'm adding an `applicationDidFinishLaunching` observer in my `viewDidLoad`, and load the data when that is triggered.

So (in order):
1. ViewController is adding an `applicationDidFinishLaunching` observer.
2. AppDelegates runs its `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and triggering the observer.
3. I can load the data from my ViewController.

---

I realized I'm **relaying** on `viewDidLoad` to be called before `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. If that order is changed, the observer will be added after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and data will not load.

Would it be 'safer' to let my 'CoreDataManager' get the `NSManagedObjectContext` from AppDelegate directly in its `init`?

Comment: The real question here is, why is `viewDidLoad` being called before `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? That's not normal. Something weird is happening, and Core Data is the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: @TomHarrington I'm afraid it is, in the land of Cocoa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681587/os-x-storyboard-calls-viewdidload-before-applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking iOS. Nevermind.

Comment: @TomHarrington You hit the big point. This is really counter intuitive where in Apple's examples, they instruct the `NSManagedObjectContext` pointer passing right in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest a revised design instead, remove any use of core data from the AppDelegate class and move any initialisation into your root view controller instead and then use dependency injection to pass your managed object context to other view controllers (or have a separate core data manager class implemented as a singleton). This will free you from issues like this.

Comment: Took me some time to realize this is really the best way. I basically just added some explanation and code, but yea, the CoreData code can be easily moved, it's one independent function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Joakim Danielson here is what I ended up doing (credit where credit is due).

**--EDIT**

Ended up doing exactly what Joakim Danielson suggested. The given code to get the context, may be in the `AppDelegate` by default, but it's completely independent. It can be moves anywhere really.
I basically moved the following func into my `CoreDataManager` class and I'm calling it in the `init()`:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Also, not to forget that the `saveContext()` in `AppDelegate` needs to be updated (by default it points to its own getter).

---

*(Previous answer:)*

I've changed (somewhat) the signature `lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer` provided in the `AppDelegate` (by checking `CoreData` when creating a project) to: `static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer`.

```
static var coreDataContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    })
    return container.viewContext
}()
```

My `CoreDataManager` (which is a singleton), can now use this init:

```
class CoreDataManager {

static let shared = CoreDataManager()

weak var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

init() {
    self.context = AppDelegate.coreDataContext
}
```

Using this pattern (in `AppDelegate`):

```
static var coreDataContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {...}()
```

Ensures that the block will be executed only once.

Now, it is safe to use the `NSManagedObjectContext` at any stage.